# Proving that charts are related

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $A$ be an atlas on the set $M$ and let $ x: U \to x(U) $ and $ y : V \to y(V )$ be bijections from subsets
$U, V \subset M$ to open sets $x(U), y(V ) \subset \mathbb{R^n} $. Show that if the charts $(x,U)$ and $(y, V )$ are each related
to every chart $(z,W) \in A$ , then $(x,U)$ is related to $(y, V )$ as well.

I can show that $x \circ y^{-1}$ and $y \circ x^{-1}$ are smooth (the first half of proof) but I am not quite sure how to prove that $x(U \cap V)$ and $y(U \cap V)$ are both open sets in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

I'd be thankful if someone can help me with this,

Comment: How did you prove that $x\circ y^{-1}$ is smooth? Shouldn't it follow from this proof that $x(U\cap V)$ is open? (Haven't done it now but that's how I remember it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's show that $x$ is a homeomorphism (same goes for $y$). It's enough to show this locally. Let $p \in U$ and let $(\varphi, W) \in A$ with $p \in W$. Since $x = (x \circ \varphi^{-1}) \circ \varphi$ on $U \cap W$, and both $\varphi$ and $x \circ \varphi^{-1}$ are homeomorphisms (because $(x,U)$ is related to $(\varphi, W)$), this shows that $x$ is a homeomorphism on $U \cap W$.

So we have showed that for any $p \in U$, $x$ is a homeomorphism restricted to some neighborhood of $p$. In other words $x : U \to x(U)$ is a local homeomorphism. Since $x$ is bijective, it is a homeomorphism.

In particular, $x(U \cap V)$ is open because $U\cap  V$ is open.

The same proof goes for $y$: $y$ is a homeomorphism so $y(U \cap V)$ is open.

Comment: We need to prove that $(x,U)$ and $(y,V)$ are related, in your solution there is no trace of $(y,V)$ ...

Comment: You were asking how to prove that $x(U \cap V)$ and $y(U \cap V)$ are open sets. I showed that $x$ is a homeomorphism (the same proof goes for $y$), which answers your question. You said in your question that you showed the other half of the proof. Am I missing something?

Comment: You have proved that $x$ is a homeomorphism on $U \cap W$ and we can similarly show that $y$ is a homeomorphism on $V \cap W$, but I do not see why $x$ is a homeo on $U \cap V$ and $y$ be a homeo on $U \cap V$ ...

Comment: Because it's enough to show that it is a local homeomorphism. Let me clarify that in the answer (see edit)